# ComboBox Hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, userform

I'm pretty new to programming and i need to finish a Project in Excel

How can i make a UserForm open a Hyperlink depending on the ComboBox selection?

This is my code. Can somebody please explain to me what to do?

```vb
    Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
    With Historie.ComboBox1
    
        .AddItem "xxx"
        .AddItem "yyy"
        .AddItem "WWW"
       
    
    End With
    
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub Historie_Change()
        Select Case Me.Historie.Value
            Case "xxx"
                Me.CommandButton1.Caption = "Zum Update"
                Me.CommandButton1.Tag = "https://www.google.com"
                
            Case "yyy"
                Me.CommandButton1.Caption = "Zum Update"
                Me.CommandButton1.Tag = "https://www.google.com"
                
            Case "WWW"
                Me.CommandButton1.Caption = "Zum Update"
                Me.CommandButton1.Tag = "https://www.google.com"
        
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
       
        If Me.CommandButton1.Tag <> "" Then
            ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=Me.CommandButton1.Tag
        End If
    
    End Sub
```

I looked around for so long and even ChatGPT couldn't give me an answer. Please help.

Comment: What is `Historie`?

Comment: its the name of the userform

Comment: The code you have posted seems to think it's the combobox - `Historie_Change` - there is no such event for a form, nor does a form have a Value. Try calling the ComboBox `Historie` and change the Initilise to `With Historie` i.e. remove `.ComboBox1`

Answer (score 1):

### Combo Box Hyperlinks

- You are referencing the combo box incorrectly.
- Additionally, the *Select* statement is 'under construction'.

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    With Me.CommandButton1
        .Caption = "Zum Update"
        Select Case Me.ComboBox1.Value
            Case "xxx": .Tag = "https://www.google.com"
            Case "yyy": .Tag = "https://www.google.com"
            Case "www": .Tag = "https://www.google.com"
            Case Else: .Tag = "": .Caption = "Kein Link"
        End Select
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Me
        .ComboBox1.List = Array("xxx", "yyy", "www")
        .CommandButton1.Caption = "Keine Auswahl"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Me.CommandButton1
        If .Tag <> "" Then ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=.Tag
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Tank you so much!